# Google Tag Manager preview a.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

When trying to use GTM preview, I'm getting the follow error in the console, which is crashing our application. I've been asked by our Analytics team to resolve the problem, but i'm not too familiar with GTM, so i'm not sure if this is a problem caused by GTM itself, or whether the error is being generated by our frontend application.

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of where I would need to start to debug this?[image]
[image]

Comment: Javascript regular expression verifier function "Match" needs a String type value. Make sure the value you're testing is a String type.

Answer (score -1):

It is causing by GTM. From the error message, looks like it is coming from one of your html tag or custom javascript variable.

A quick way to check the problem:

1. Export the GTM container and download the `json` file.
2. Open the `json` file in text and search for `.match`.
3. You should see some code and debug for them. Most of the situation is we need to determine the variable is string or not then do the `match` function.